# Question on convergence involving one-to-one functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Could someone please explain how the following problem is solved?

> Suppose that $lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=c$ and that $\sigma:\Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}$ be one-to-one. Prove that $lim_{n\to\infty}s_{\sigma(n)}=c$.
>
> Hint : Since $\sigma$ is one-to-one, then the set {$n\in\Bbb{N}$: $ \sigma(n) \leq N $} is finite for any N $\in \Bbb{N}$.

**Throw-away attempt :**

Assume $<s_n>$ converges to c and let $\sigma:\Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}$ be one-to-one. Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be a real number. The idea,if i understand it corectly, invovlves reverse engineering a natural number $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that for all $n \gt N$, $|s_{\sigma(n)}-c| \lt \epsilon$.

Therefore:

$|s_{\sigma(n)}-c| = |(s_{\sigma(n)}-s_n)+(s_n-c)| \leq |(s_{\sigma(n)}-s_n)|+|(s_n-c)|$

...now since $<s_n>$ converges to c then by definition there exists some $N_s \in \Bbb{N}$ such that for $n \gt N_s$ , $|s_n-c|$ can be made as small as necessary..

but what do i do with the other term $|(s_{\sigma(n)}-s_n)|$ ? and how is the hint involved ?

Thank you for any clarifications.

---

**New Attempt :**

Suppose,for a contradiction,that $lim_{n\to\infty}s_{\sigma(n)}=d$ where d is not equal to c. By definition, for every $U_\epsilon$ of d, there is a $\sigma(N) \in \Bbb{N}$ s.t. for all $\sigma(n) \gt \sigma(N)$, $s_{\sigma(n)} \in U_{\epsilon}$. By corollary, every $U_{\epsilon}$ contains an infinite number of points from the sequence $<s_{\sigma(n)}>$.

However,setting $N \geq \sigma(n_p)$ where $s_{\sigma(n_p)} \gt d+ \epsilon$ yields two contradictory results :

(i) By the hint that {$n\in\Bbb{N}$: $ \sigma(n) \leq N $} is finite for any N $\in \Bbb{N}$, it follows that there are a finite number of $\sigma(n)$ points.

(ii) Now,if there are infinite $s_{\sigma(n)}$ terms in $U_{\epsilon}$,there must be infinite points of $\sigma(n)$ to serve as the index of the terms of the sequence located in $U_{\epsilon}$.

er....does this make a bit more sense??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is very easy if you argue by contradiction, can you see?

Assume your subsequence converges to $d\neq c$.

Then you can show that your original sequence is not convergent, since for any $N$ there always exist infinity many $n$ such that $n>N$, $\sigma(n)$ is closer to $d$ than to $c$.

This statement can be easily made mathematical rigorous using $\epsilon$, care to do the honor?

---

I will do the honor:

> **$\exists N$ such that $\forall n>N$ and $\sigma(n)>N$, $|s_n-c|\leq\frac{|d-c|}{4}$ and
>   $|s_{\sigma(n)}-d|\leq\frac{|d-c|}{4}$.**

(infinitely many terms in $\sigma(n)$ satisfy this since by the hint there are only finitely many before $N$)

> **Hence $|s_n-s_{\sigma(n)}|\geq\frac{|d-c|}{2}$. Since $s_{\sigma(n)}$ is also in $s_n$, the sequence $s_n$ diverges.
>   Contradiction.**

(In this last statement I cooked up some distance such that $s_n$ and $s_{\sigma(n)}$ must be that close to their limits. This makes a gap between the terms in them, which creates the contradiction)

Comment: Thank you for your response...i am afraid i am still confused! Suppose,for contradiction, that $<s_{\sigma (n)}>$ converges to d (not equal to c). Then $|s_{\sigma (n)}-d|$ can be made as small as necessary for n>N...but by the hint $n \gt N \geq \sigma(n)$?? therefore $s_n$ is further in the tails than $s_{\sigma (n)}$??...i do not think i am making any sense here ! :-\

Comment: the hint says that there are finitely many terms of $\sigma(n)$ before any given $N$. This means after $N$ there are infinitely many $\sigma(n)$ that visit a arbitrarily small neighborhood of $d$. Does this make sense?

Comment: hmm...thank you again...maybe i am missing something since my text book is not a real analysis book but merely a 'transition' book. you mentioned 'subsequence'..i do not know what that is ... Are you perhaps treating $\sigma (n)$ itself as a sequence ? Is it possible to solve the problem without this notion? thank you for your patience.

Comment: would you mind taking a look at my new attempt in the OP please?...it is probably still wrong,but i am  just using stuff in the book

Comment: Your new approach's observation 2 is on the right path. 1 is, unless I'm not understanding, incorrect. It's either saying the same thing as 2 is saying or it is saying something exotic that I don't understand (incorrect). Can you attempt to find a distance based on c and d that some terms of the same sequence are at least that much apart? -- this is the contradiction can you see?

Comment: Thank you for the honour.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\lim_{n\to \infty}s_n=c$ iff for every $r>0$ the set $S(r)=\{n: |s_n-c|\ge r\}$ is finite. (This could even be used as the definition of a limit.)

And $\lim_{n\to \infty} s_{\sigma(n)}=c$ iff for every $r>0$  the set $\Sigma(r)=\{n:|s_{\sigma(n)}-c|\ge r\}$ is finite.

Let $T(r)=\sigma^{-1}S(r)=\{n: \sigma(n)\in S(r)\}.$ Then $T(r)$ is finite because $S(r)$ is finite and $\sigma$ is $1$-to-$1$.

And $T(r)=\Sigma(r).$

Comment: This also works if $\sigma:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ is finite-to-$1,$  which means that for every $n$ the set $\sigma^{-1}\{n\}=\{m:\sigma(m)=n\}$ is finite.

Comment: would you mind taking a look at my new attempt in the OP please?...it is probably still wrong, but your approach is..a bit advanced for me i think. Thanks

Comment: I see a logical flaw in the first sentence of your new attempt. If you prove by contadiction that $\neg (\lim_{n\to \infty}s_{\sigma(n)}=d)$ for any $d\ne c,$ you have not proved that the limit is $c$. Rather, you have proved that either there is no limit or that there is a limit of $c.$..... BTW if you examine the  $definition$ of $\lim_{n\to \infty}s_n=c$ you will soon see that (in the notation of my A)  it is $exactly$  (in the notation of my A)  the requirement that $S(r)$ is finite for every $r>0.$ It is a convenient and useful way of looking at limits